# Avoiding redundant type conversion code

Tags: c#, parsing, type-conversion

I've come across this code in one of our applications and thought it was was redundant.

```
string oldAdjRate = SomeDataTable.Rows[0]["SomeColumn"].ToString();
double oAdjRate;
if (double.TryParse(oldAdjRate, out oAdjRate))
{
    oAdjRate = double.Parse(oldAdjRate);
}
```

This is done for a couple other values so it takes a good a amount of space up.

Can't this be reduced to the following?

```
string oldAdjRate = SomeDataTable.Rows[0]["SomeColumn"].ToString();
double oAdjRate = double.TryParse(oldAdjRate, out oAdjRate) ? oAdjRate: 0;
```

What's the purpose of doing `double.TryParse` to then actually just `double.Parse` it in the original code. (Besides checking if we can parse it first) Can't we just reduce one of the parse conditions out and use a conditional operator?

Comment: Why are you storing numeric data as a string in that data source to begin with?  Store numeric data as a numeric value, else you'll run into all sorts of problems.

Comment: @Servy That is also something I noticed also.

Answer (score 1):

`TryParse()` always assigns a value to `oAdjRate`. You do not need to assign it yourself.

Now, the value may not be what you want. If TryParse returns true, then the conversion succeeded, and the value of `oAdjRate` will be correct. However, if TryParse returns false, the value of `oAdjRate` will be zero.

You have to decide what to do when the conversion fails. For example, here I've decided to throw an exception.

```
string strVal = "12.3";
double dVal;
if (double.TryParse(strVal , out dVal))
{
    // Here, the value of dVal is 12.3
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dVal);
}
else
{
    // Here, the value of dVal is 0.0
    throw new ArgumentException()
}

// Here, we don't know what dVal is. It could be 12.3 or 0.0.
```

Here's the relevant [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ```
> public static bool TryParse(
>   string s,
>   out double result
> )
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> *result*
> When this method returns, contains the double-precision floating-point
> number equivalent of the s parameter, if the conversion succeeded, or
> zero if the conversion failed. The conversion fails if the s parameter
> is null or String.Empty, is not a number in a valid format, or
> represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue. This
> parameter is passed uninitialized; any value originally supplied in
> result will be overwritten.

Comment: tl;dr: yes, you can reduce it to the ternary :).

Comment: well no - the ternary is not needed since it will load 0 in the case of failure

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan In the true case it assigns a variable to itself, which is pointless. And like pm100 said, in the false case it assigns zero to a variable that is already zero, which is also pointless.

Comment: Pointless, but possible. The question was "Can't we just reduce one of the parse conditions out and use a conditional operator?" and the answer is "yes, if you really want to". Rather than throwing an exception in the `else` case, you could just use `Parse`, since that's what it would do anyway.